# Add custom controls to Kibana dashboard?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I am looking to use Kibana for monitoring real-time data.

I would like to add some custom controls onto the dashboard such as buttons and drop down menus... to apply a certain filter to the data etc. 
This is to make it more fluid and easier to use for a particular user.

How do I go about doing this? There is not a lot of informaiton on how to add this kind of funcitonality online. I assume I should be looking into creating my own custom plug-ins?

Many thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

look at the next link
[Kibana plugins tutorial](https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/)
And this:
[Plugin generator](https://github.com/elastic/generator-kibana-plugin)